IK Leg is either rotated wrongly or bends wrongly
I have a model, but when I tried to put Inverse Kinematics, the leg will either bend backwards, or the leg will be rotated wrongly. I've tried to rotate bones, rotate Pole Angle, move the Pole Target... But whatever I do, the problem always stays the same. Is there any way to fix this?

In Edit mode, bend the knee a bit forwards so that Blender knows in what direction it is supposed to bend, then in Pose mode correct its Pole Angle if necessary:

